# Retrieving all 32 bit process modules from 64 bit application (C#)

Tags: c#, process, module

I have a 64 bit program that retrieving process modules from other processes but when i try to get modules form 32 bit processes i get only:

1. Application executable. - various
2. ntdll.dll - always
3. wow64.dll - always
4. wow64cpu.dll - always
5. wow64win.dll - always

but process have many other modules.

Can i get all 32 bit process modules from 64 bit application(C#)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll need p/invoke.

- [EnumProcessModulesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633.aspx)

It's possible that the DbgHelp API could be coaxed to do this, but I've been told that despite having appropriately-sized structures, it returns only the 64-bit WOW64 emulation layer DLLs when called against a Win32-on-Win64 process.

- [EnumerateLoadedModules64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679316.aspx)

Comment: In fact this has the same bitness limitations as the tool help API (tested with dbghelp 6.1 from Windows 7 system dir) and so produces the same output as in the question. Looks like I fired my up vote too soon.  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: fixed, I think

Comment: Yes, I think that's accurate. I think that after you correcting me at least 50 times here, this might be the first time in the other direction. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The wow64* modules are the thunking layer to x86.  All your x86 modules should show up as being loaded by the thunking modules.